# AIX monitoring directory changes

Tags: aix

I'm on AIX 5.3 and I'm a total noob with that OS.
I was wondering if there is something like inotify on AIX so that one can monitor directories and files for changes instead of polling.
I'm going to do this from Java so solutions using Java or C (I can just wrap it with jni or jna) are fine. I'd rather not use any shell scripting or system configuration stuff.

Comment: should as superuser.com or serverfault

Comment: Looks like he wants code to do this ("from Java"), so I think it's in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

you could try looking to see if there are hooks into audit, which sounds like it could be have the functionality you want.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/audit.htm

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's a bit late :) the program in question has already been handed over to maintenance. Perhaps I will look into it again if there needs to be a version 2 made.